# Best hardware to build android os platform code Version 15

Tags: android, android-source

Can you share how the best possible laptop or virtual machine configuration to use to build Android version 15 very very fast..

Also, pl. share how much has it taken to repo sync and m commands to complete as per your experience

ref: https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build/building